# Determining the sequence of two clicks a user makes

Tags: java, user-interface, event-handling, jbutton

```
public class GlassActionListener{

    JButton first;
    JButton second;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(first == null)
        {
            first = (JButton) e.getSource();
        }
        else
        {
            second = (JButton) e.getSource();

            // do something

            // clean up
            first = null;
            second = null;
        }   
    }
}

public class GUIControl {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                showGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void showGUI() {  

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyFrame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JButton glass1 = new JButton("glass1");
        JButton glass2 = new JButton("glass2");
        JButton glass3 = new JButton("glass3");

        frame.getContentPane().add(glass1);
        frame.getContentPane().add(glass2);
        frame.getContentPane().add(glass3);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        glass1.addActionListener(??);
        glass2.addActionListener(??);
        glass3.addActionListener(??);

        // I want to store the first two clicks in these variables
        from = "glassX";
        to = "glassY";

        puzzle.move(from, to);
    }
```

The user will spill soda between the glasses. The first JButton the user clicks out of the three available determines the "from" initial glass and the second JButton the user clicks out of the three available determines the "to" destination glass.

How can I determine the specific two JButtons that the user clicked? 
Everytime the user clicks two out of the three JButtons I want to store the string associated with those two JButtons in a "from" and "to" variable.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

make an `ActionListener` and use `JButton#addActionListener` to add it to all three buttons. The event has a source field you can use.

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
    JButton first;
    JButton second;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(first == null)
        {
            first = (JButton) e.getSource();
        }
        else
        {
            second = (JButton) e.getSource();

            // do something

            // clean up
            first = null;
            second = null;
        }   
    }
};


glass1.addActionListener(listener);
glass2.addActionListener(listener);
glass3.addActionListener(listener);
```

Handling the logic inside the listener is a little dirty, but that's the idea.

Comment: Can you please show me the implementation if I want to just create one class called JButtonGlassActionListener and add instances of this class to each JButton?

Comment: do it as above, but simply move the contents of the listener to your new class

Comment: Ok but what should I do in the "\\ do something part"?

Comment: I’m assuming that once you have the “from” glass and the “to” glass, you want to perform a pour action or “something” and then reset the listener state

Comment: I want the first and second variables in the ShowGUI method to store the move

Comment: Yes exactly, I want to call a move function on the "from" and "to". Like move(from, to)

Comment: Can I do that outside the Listener class?

Comment: If I decide to call move(from, to) in the ShowGUI method, how should I code the listener class?

Comment: Sorry, I am a little new to GUI

Comment: that’s okay, we all start somewhere. If you leave the listener as an anonymous inner class, you can call the move directly from the listener, where the “do something” is

Comment: The move method is actually part of a Puzzle class. In my Listener class should I add a instance variable called private Puzzle puzzle and then inside the actionPerformed method, can I do puzzle.move(from, to)?

Comment: that would work, but sounds funky from a design perspective

Comment: Could you please have a look at my updated code? I kind of used your Listener class. Could you please help me accomplish what I'm trying to get at.

Answer (score 0):

```
firstbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    //do something here first button is clicked
  } 
} );
```

you can add listeners to buttons like this.and use a class variable to track how many times the buttons are clicked.

eg:

```
public class GUIControl {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            showGUI();
        }
    });
}



public static void showGUI() {  
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyFrame");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JButton glass1 = new JButton("glass1");
    JButton glass2 = new JButton("glass2");
    JButton glass3 = new JButton("glass3");

    String from = "";
    String to = "";
    int click_count = 0;


glass1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    if(click_count ==0)
    {
       from = "glassX";
       click_count = 1;
    }else if(click_count ==1)
    {
       from = "glassY";
       click_count = 0;
    }
  } 
} );

glass2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    if(click_count ==0)
    {
       from = "glassX";
       click_count = 1;
    }else if(click_count ==1)
    {
       from = "glassY";
       click_count = 0;
    }
  } 
} );

glass3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    if(click_count ==0)
    {
       from = "glassX";
       click_count = 1;
    }else if(click_count ==1)
    {
       from = "glassY";
       click_count = 0;
    }
  } 
} );

    frame.getContentPane().add(glass1);
    frame.getContentPane().add(glass2);
    frame.getContentPane().add(glass3);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    // I want to store the first two clicks in these variables
}
```